# `argparse` multiple choice argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` to parse the Python command line which is supposed to look like this:

```
python script_name.py --sdks=first, second
```

My script looks like this:

```
sdk_choises = ['aio','sw']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Blah blah')
parser.add_argument('--sdks', action='append', nargs='+', required=True, help='specifies target SDK(s)')
args = parser.parse_args()
if 'aio' in args.sdks:
   # do something with aio
if 'sw' in args.sdks:
   # do something with sw
```

When I execute: 
`python script_name.py --sdks=aio, sw` I get error:

```
"usage: script.py [-h] --sdks SDKS [SDKS ...]  
build.py: error: unrecognized arguments: sw"
```

I'd like to be able to choose one or all choices:

```
python script_name.py --sdks=first
python script_name.py --sdks=second
python script_name.py --sdks=first, second
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You certainly have to remove the comma: `python script_name.py --sdks aio sw`

Comment: The error is the same without comma. How is the separator specified? Is it space, or comma?

Comment: I think it depends on your shell, but the separator is often ' '. I've just tested your code (python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14.04.3), it's alright for me :/ The error must be located in build.py

Comment: I've run `python test.py --sdks aio, sw`, and printing `args` give `Namespace(sdks=[['aio,', 'sw']])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works nice:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Blah blah')
parser.add_argument('--sdks', nargs='+', required=True, help='specifies target SDK(s)')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.sdks)
```

You don't need the `=` when passing options, just use:

```
$ python test.py --sdks ai pw
['ai', 'pw']
```

Comment: Actually, it works with the `append` action too, but gives `args.sdks == [['aio', 'sw']]`:)

Comment: OK, found it. I was using `--sdks=aio sw' instead of '--sdks aio sw`. So without `=`. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please remove the `append` action sentence, action seems to work OK here with action='store'. And please state the = problem so I can accept your answer.

Comment: You are not using variable ``sdk_choices`` anywhere.

Comment: OK, removed the line `sdk_choices` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer your original form of the comma-separated list, plus check if the argument is valid, then I recommend:

```
parser.add_argument('--sdks', nargs=1, type=lambda s: [sdk_choises[sdk_choises.index(f)] for f in s.split(',')], ...
```

Even cleaner way is to define it in a separate function similar to lambda above:

```
parser.add_argument('--sdks', nargs=1, type=my_parse_function, ...
```

argparse docs has examples for the parsing function with proper error reporting.
With nargs=1 you'd need to remove one extra list layer.